Finding a Counterexample in Well-Ordered Sets
Given a well-ordered set W and an element a from W, I want to find a counterexample to the following proposition:
"If a is the supremum of W<a> in W (supW<a>), then a does not have an immediate predecessor in W."
In the textbook I am currently reading, there is a proof for the converse of the following proposition. However, there is no proof provided for the proposition itself, leading me to wonder whether it generally does not hold, and I am looking for any counterexamples. If there are no counterexamples to this proposition, I would greatly appreciate it if you could also provide a proof of the proposition.

What does W<a> stand for?

My apologies, W represents the section of W at a.
W = {x|x∈ W, x<a}

Assume that $p$ is the immediate predecessor of $a$. Then $p<a$ and there is no element in between. Which means that if $x<a$ then $x\leq p$. In particular $p$ is an upper bound of $W\langle a\rangle$ as well, but strictly smaller than $a$. Which is a contradiction, because $a$ is the supremum.

Hint ... if $u$ is an upper bound of $w\langle a\rangle$ and $v$ is an immediate predecessor of $u$ then $v$ is an upper bound of $w\langle a\rangle$.

Thanks! Your answer resolved the issue!!
